# seekbar with multiple thumbs

Tags: android, seekbar, android-seekbar, seekbar-thumb

I need help to create a seekbar with multiple thumbs.
Currently, I have a seekbar going from 1-100 KM. I am able to move the thumb in a fixed interval 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 etc.
I need help to move the thumb in flexible intervals etc 1,2,5,10,20,50,100.

Currently, I have the following:

```
    seekLocation.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            txtDistanceIncrease.setText(UnitConverter.getSeekbarDistanceByType(prefUtils, progress));

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: you can detect for changes, then programmatically snap them to the seekbar when the user finish moving it.

Answer (score 0):

you can try snapping your seekbar to the nearest interval when the user moves the progressbar. (e.g. 10 to 15 snaps to 10; 15 to 30 snaps to 20, etc...) kinda like the following.

```
int[] x_value = {1,2,5,10,20,50,100,..};
int maxValue = maxOf(x_value);
int minValue = minOf(x_value); 

seekbar.setMax(maxValue -minValue);
```

then at the seekbar onProgressChanged listener

```
onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser){

   if(fromUser){
    int x = progress + minValue;
    //snap progress to the nearest x_value
    int nearestX = getNearestXValue(x, x_value);
    seekbar.setProgress(nearestX);

    updateChartline(nearestX);
   }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have just shown the codes I currently have. 
Where should I insert the first part of your answer? thanks

Comment: you can insert the first part right after you call findViewById for your seekbar.